# SpringBoot v1.5.14.RELEASE - Reading files from test Resource Folder

Tags: java, spring, file, spring-boot, resources

I want to read a file that I have inside the test folder

```
../resources/files/ElTimoDeLaEstampeta.json
```

So I create this function that works when the file is on the folder

`../resources/ElTimoDeLaEstampeta.json`

```
protected String getResourceFileAsString (String resourceFileName) throws Exception {
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(resourceFileName);
    return new String(IOUtils.toByteArray(resource.getInputStream()));
}
```

But when is inside the files folder I got an exception, I've tried with  with the same result

```
getResourceFileAsString ("files/ElTimoDeLaEstampeta.json") 
getResourceFileAsString ("/files/ElTimoDeLaEstampeta.json") 
getResourceFileAsString ("files.ElTimoDeLaEstampeta.json");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read a file from resources folder you have to use the class loader.

Try the following code:

```java
@Test
    public void readFile() throws Exception {
        InputStream inputStream = MaestroTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("folder/file.json");
        String data = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(data);
    }
```